# installing oci8-2.0.10 for linux mint 17

Tags: php, linux, linux-mint, oci8

For connecting oracle with laravel I need to install `oci8`. As I have `php 5.5.9` I have to install `oci8-2.0.10`.

To install I used first `pecl install oci8-2.0.10`. But failed. 
Then I used `pecl -vvv install oci8-2.0.10` to force verbosity. But still it isn't finding `oci8-2.0.10`.

Then I go to [pecl php website](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8) and downloaded `oci8-2.0.10.tgz` file. But there is no binary or make file. And scary is that this may be for windows though I am not sure.

Aside all I just need a solution to get done my task of installing `oci8-2.0.10`. How to do this?

Comment: Is it a question for http://superuser.com ?

Comment: No idea where it is or not. Trying for two days to do this, still not found anything.

Comment: @shellter,I did that, but return me an error saying oci8 requires php>=7.0.0. 
Btw, I installed oci8-2.0.10 and wrote down it as answer. [this is a reply to shellter but he removed his comment.]

Answer (score 2):

```
pear install oci8-2.0.10.tgz
```

Does the trick installing the oci8-2.0.10.tgz file. It will ask a path for the oracle instant client.If given correctly, the job is done.